# Sum of two numbers in array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

**The task**

> You are given two non-empty arrays representing two non-negative
>   integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their
>   items contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as an
>   array.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except
>   the number 0 itself.
>
> Example: Input: [2,4,3] + [5,6,4] Output: [7,0,8]

```
const a1 = [2,4,3];
const a2 = [5,6,4];
```

**My imperative solution**

```
function addTwoNumbers(a1, a2) {
  const len = a1.length > a2.length ? a1.length : a2.length;
  const res = [];
  let memo = 0;

  const sanitize = n => n ? n : 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      let sum = sanitize(a1[i]) + sanitize(a2[i]) + memo;
      memo = sum > 9 ? sum % 9 : 0;
      sum = sum > 9 ? sum % 10 : sum;
      res.push(sum);
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(addTwoNumbers(a1, a2));
```

**My functional solution**

```
const range = num => Array.from(new Array(num), (_, i) => i);

const addTwoNumbers2 = (a1, a2) => {
  const sanitize = n => n ? n : 0;
  const len = a1.length > a2.length ? a1.length : a2.length;
  const {res} = range(len)
  .reduce((acc,i) => {
    let sum = sanitize(a1[i]) + sanitize(a2[i]) + acc.memo;
    acc.memo = sum > 9 ? sum % 9 : 0;
    sum = sum > 9 ? sum % 10 : sum;
    acc.res.push(sum);
    return acc;
  }, {res: [], memo: 0,});
  return res;
};

console.log(addTwoNumbers2(a1, a2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bug

Unfortunately both your functions return bad results for many input arguments. You don't carry.

Both should return [0,1] however they return [0]

```
addTwoNumbers([1], [9]); // >> [0] wrong
addTwoNumbers2([1], [9]);  // >> [0] wrong
```

And the return for the following should be [6,0,1] but they return [6,6]

```
addTwoNumbers([9], [7, 9]);  // >> [6, 6] wrong
addTwoNumbers2([9], [7, 9]);  // >> [6, 6] wrong
```

The reason is that you forget to deal with the carry.

### To number?

[Konijn's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/217580/120556) is a tempting solution but will also fail as it is limited by JS Number.

```
addTwoNumbers([1,1,9,9,0,4,7,4,5,2,9,9,1,7,0,0,9], [1,9,9,0,4,7,4,5,2,9,9,1,7,0,0,9])
```

The correct answer is

[2,0,9,0,5,1,2,0,8,1,9,1,9,7,0,9,9]

However Konijn's solution incorrectly returns.

[0,0,9,0,5,1,2,0,8,1,9,1,9,7,0,9,9]

This is because the second number is [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) above which you can not get a reliable result.

### [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

You could use a [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) as its size is not limited.

Big ints can be written with the suffix n

```
 const big = 9907919180215090099079191802150900n;  // Note the suffix n
```

To convert the reversed number to a big int

```
 const a = [0,0,9,0,5,1,2,0,8,1,9,1,9,7,0,9,9,0,0,9,0,5,1,2,0,8,1,9,1,9,7,0,9,9];
 const big = BigInt(a.reverse().join(""));
```

Thus your function would be

```
 const addTwoNumbers = (a, b) => (
          BigInt(a.reverse().join("")) + 
          BigInt(b.reverse().join(""))
      ).toString().split("").reverse();
```

But that takes the puz out of puzzle me thinks.

### Carry

The aim is to carry the remainder of each addition onto the next digit. This is fundamental to all [ALU (Arithmetic Logic Units)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) that are part of almost every modern CPU. (In the case of binary the carry is 1 or 0)

So when you add two values 9 + 9 the result is 8 and carry 1. You then add the 1 to the next digit. If no digit add it to zero. The result is 18.

The function is thus

Example A

```
function addNumbers(a, b) {
    const sum = [];
    var i = 0, carry = 0;
    while (i < a.length || i < b.length || carry > 0) {
        carry += (a[i] ? a[i] : 0) + (b[i] ? b[i] : 0);
        sum.push(carry % 10);
        carry = carry / 10 | 0;
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**Note** That it continues adding digits until the carry is zero.

### Performance

I am not surprised that the big int solution is nearly 7 times slower than carry method (example A) above, but this is due to the `reverse`s, `join`s, and `split`

Big int are not fast (Very slow compared to standard JS numbers), doing the same sum on big int literals is only 5 times faster than the carry method (example A)

### NOTES

[BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) is very new and you should check the browser for support before using it.

Big int also sees the arrival of 64bit int arrays (YAY YAY YAY) [`BigUint64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigUint64Array), [`BigInt64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt64Array) (sorry MDN has empty pages on these references)

Answer (score 1):

From a short review

- I prefer to read short words or acronyms, so `len` -> `length` ideally
- Consider `Math.max()` to determine the lengthiest array
- From the challenge, it seems there is no need to sanitize anything
- `addTwoNumbers` <- this name should give a hint that perhaps the approach is wrong

This is my counter proposal:

```
const a1 = [2,4,3];
const a2 = [5,6,4];

function addTwoNumbers(nl1, nl2) {

  function toNumber(digitList){
    return digitList.reverse().join('') * 1;
  } 

  return (toNumber(nl1) + toNumber(nl2) + '').split('').reverse();
}

console.log(addTwoNumbers(a1, a2));
```